# How to return a list on mongodb field where the field is an array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a collection where in a field contains an Array:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "words" : [
                "9J",
                "4AAQSKZJRGABAAQAAAQABAAD",
                "MEDIAMESSAGE",
                "MMSMESSAGE",
                "NOTE",
                "HTTPS",
                "MEU_TEST_PIPE",
                "MEU_TEST_SEMICOLON",
                "EUSOUOELEMENTONOVO",
                "ELEMENTOMAISNOVO",
                "AAAH",
                "UAI",
                "BAH"
        ]
}
```

I need to get all array in "words" field. I would get like return an object look likes:

```
["9J", "4AAQSKZJRGABAAQAAAQABAAD", "MEDIAMESSAGE", "MMSMESSAGE", "NOTE", "HTTPS", "MEU_TEST_PIPE", "MEU_TEST_SEMICOLON", "EUSOUOELEMENTONOVO", "ELEMENTOMAISNOVO", "AAAH", "UAI", "BAH"]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Use projection.

Comment: I don't know a lot about mongodb.

I wrote a query like:  `db.mycollection.aggregate([{'$unwind': '$words'}])` where the return was:

`{ "_id" : 1, "words" : "9J" }
{ "_id" : 1, "words" : "4AAQSKZJRGABAAQAAAQABAAD" }
{ "_id" : 1, "words" : "MEDIAMESSAGE" }
{ "_id" : 1, "words" : "MMSMESSAGE" }
{ "_id" : 1, "words" : "AAAH" }
{ "_id" : 1, "words" : "UAI" }
{ "_id" : 1, "words" : "BAH" }`

Comment: I answered this.

Comment: @whoami, yes, is it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
db.mycollection.find({}).projection({"words": 1})
```

Comment: Sorry about the last comment. In this case, the return is equal to db.mycollection.find({}).
It returned all fields.

Comment: Then provide a filter inside find first like find({"_id" : 1}) . This will return only the document with id 1